# How to get the build variant at runtime in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to get the build variant during runtime, is this possible without any extra config or code?

Comment: For checking only debug or not,  `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {}`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Look at the generated `BuildConfig` class.

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.example.app";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "";
}
```

Comment: So if your app hasn't been built yet, this class wouldn't exist and using the class before it gets built would cause a compile error, wouldn't it? Isn't this the chicken vs. egg scenario?

Comment: BuildConfig is generated during a Gradle Sync, not the building of the app itself.

Comment: Friendly reminder to import the BulidConfig for *your* app package instead of from an external library BuildConfig...as I did...

Comment: `PACKAGE_NAME` seems to have been replaced by `APPLICATION_ID`

Comment: @ashishduh "BuildConfig is generated during a Gradle Sync, not the building of the app itself." Nope, that's not right. Just clean the project and you'll notice `BuildConfig` is gone. It is called *BuildConfig* for a reason

Answer (score 42):

Another option would be to create a separate build config variable for each build variant and use it in your code like this:

In your build.gradle file:

```
productFlavors {

    production {
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_VARIANT", "\"prod\""
    }

    dev {
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_VARIANT", "\"dev\""
    }       
}
```

To use it in your code:

```
if (BuildConfig.BUILD_VARIANT.equals("prod")){ // do something cool }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example to define and get `BuildConfig` for different flavor

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {

        develop {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }

        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".stg"
            versionNameSuffix "-stg"
        }

        production {
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            versionNameSuffix ""
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        def BASE_URL = ""

        if (variant.getName().contains("develop")) {
            BASE_URL = "https://localhost:8080.com/"
        } else if (variant.getName().contains("staging")) {
            BASE_URL = "https://stagingdomain.com/"
        } else if (variant.getName().contains("production")) {
            BASE_URL = "https://productdomain.com/"
        }
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"${BASE_URL}\""

    }
}
```

**Using**

`BuildConfig.BASE_URL`

Answer (score 5):

You can try with

```
getPackageName();
```

it will return what you've defined in build.gradle

```
productFlavours{
  flavour1{
     applicationId 'com.example.package.flavour1'
  }
  flavour2{
     applicationId 'com.example.package.flavour2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are already flavoring then no need to provide extra string field in your gradle. Just follow simple steps to get the build details:

> For build variant : **BuildConfig.FLAVOR** 
>   For build version code : **BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE** 
>   For build version name : **BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME**

Comment: `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE` should be used for the build variant. `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` should be used for any flavors that you have specified.

Answer (score 3):

you can check direct with BuildConfig and your **config name** in everwhere, BuildConfig has already BuildType

```
if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "release"){// TODO}

if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "staging"){ //TODO }

if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "debug"){ //TODO }
```