# Share a Dagger 2 component between two different flavors

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have two flavors: pro and free. In each of these, I have a MainActivity, but I want the `MainComponent` and `MainModule` to be the same for both, so `MainComponent` and `MainModule` are both in src/java/main, but I get an error in my MainComponent due to not having an import of MainActivity of both flavors. Here, let me make it clear:

Here's what the `MainComponent` in src/java/main looks like:

```
import com.xxx.myapp.di.modules.MainModule;
import com.xxx.myapp.free.MainActivity;
import com.xxx.myapp.presenters.MainPresenterImpl;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MainModule.class})
public interface MainComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(MainPresenterImpl mainPresenter);
}
```

In the code shown above, it only imports the `MainActivity` from the free flavor, hence giving an error when I switch to the pro flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using flavors you should not have different packages for the different components.

Instead of `com.xxx.myapp.free.MainActivity`
Move MainActivity up a level to `com.xxx.myapp.MainActivity` both versions of MainActivity must have the same fully qualified named.

**UPDATE**

You have two classes named `MainActivity` but to Java they have different fully qualified names `com.xxx.myapp.free.MainActivity` and `com.xxx.myapp.pro.MainActivity` (just a guess).

What you really need is one class `com.xxx.myapp.MainActivity` with flavor specific implementations. YOu can add a separate implementation of MainActivity to each flavor by the flavor specific folder paths.

`app/src/free/java/com/xxx/myapp/MainActivity.java`
`app/src/pro/java/com/xxx/myapp/MainActivity.java`

Gradle will only compile the implementation for the selected flavor.

Comment: But  I require a different MainActivity for different flavors

Comment: I am having a conflict though. The imports of `MainComponent` have to adjusted manually by me when I switch flavors. Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: but both my flavors have different package names (or applicationIDs) which is what is causing both `MainAcitivty` to have different fully qualified names. How would I go about this if both flavors had different package names? Should src/java/main contain `MainAcitivity` if I want to have it's implementation in both flavors? From what I've read, it should not.

Comment: You can use separate application ID's and still share activities. You just need to fully qualify the name of your activities in your android manifest.. Meaning instead of writing 
android:name=".MainActivity" you would write android:name="com.xxx.myapp.MainActivity"

Comment: @MattWolfe `android:name="com.xxx.myapp.MainActivity" ` would work if I had `MainActivity` in src/java/main, isn't it? But I don't. I have it in the different flavor packages. Or am I going about this in a wrong way?

Comment: ApplicationIDs and manifest configurations can also be configured by either adding different versions of the manifest to the flavor folders (see manifest merger) or by adding manifest placeholder arguments to your gradle file.

Comment: I have three different manifest files. One in src/java/main, src/java/pro and src/java/free. The one in free is different from the other two, in that, I've declared the meta-data for ads. Could you tell me what change I must make to have one class with flavor specific implementations? Should I have the class in all 3 packages? Or just in the 2 flavors?

Comment: Going back to the basics: so If I have `MainActivity` in just src/java/main, but want a different implementation of it in src/java/free, what must I do?

Comment: My answer does not relate to manifest configuration, that is a separate issue and can be done different ways. Also Manifest (along with other resources such as Strings.xml) have special rules that allow for the contents of the files to be merged.

Comment: You should not have MainActivity in your main folder. You should have one implementation in each flavor (pro, free). Gradle will only add one to the build path (your select flavor). You can think of it as if gradle copies all of the files from your current flavor into main at compile time.

Comment: I would just have 1 MainActivity personally and determine the flavor at runtime, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431354/how-to-get-the-build-variant-at-runtime-in-android-studio

Comment: @cyroxis That's exactly what I've done, but that leads to a conflict in `MainComponent`, where I can import only of the two flavor's `MainActivity`

Comment: @MattWolfe, yeah, that's good way of going about it, but I'm trying to familiarize myself with product flavors, and I'd like to try and get it done this way for the sake of learning.

Comment: @stack Read from the posted Dagger 2 module you have import com.xxx.myapp.free.MainActivity; That dagger module can only ever provide the class with that exact fully qualified name. If you want a different "MainActivity" inject into the dagger for different flavors you need two different MainActivity implementations.

Comment: There are many different way you can configuration your project and your manifest, but your question was how to have two different "MainActivites" inject into the same module.

Comment: @cyroxis, I do have two different implementations, but I can only import one into `MainComponent` class which is in src/java/main

Comment: @stack - Yes that has been my point the entire time, that is why you need two different MainActivity implementation (neither of which are in main).

Comment: Yeah, and that's exactly how I have it. But that leads to a conflict in `MainComponent` where I can only import one. Haha.

Comment: @stack - then you do not have it as I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @stack I get what cyroxis is saying now.. You need to use the same package name for both, don't use free/pro inside the actual java package name.. Just use the same package but inside the free/pro subfolder under src.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the flavor at runtime by using BuildConfig.FLAVOR and from there you can selectively add advertisements and what not. I would personally do it this way.