# Build type is always "Release"

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am obtaining that BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE returns always "release", even if I am compiling it in debug mode.

I include here a part of my build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            //md5 sign certificate split in two
            proguardFile './dexguard-config/dexguard-release-conservative.pro'
            //proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release-aggressive.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23432225/3981656

Comment: Are you importing the BuildConfig for that particular module?

Comment: @laalto you were 100% corrrect for me. i was importing the build config for react native. not my own project!

Comment: Ok, good to hear it was helpful, even if some time has passed. I expanded the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are importing `BuildConfig` of your own module, with the package name from its `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Other modules' `BuildConfig`s might be hardwired to `release`.

Comment: A-ha! Thank you! =)

Answer (score -2):

Correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639241/4922328

Old Answer:

Check your option in Build Variants in Android Studio.