# How to keep certain Build Variant selected in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I understand from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) (reproduced below) that the **`Build Variants`** are generated during Gradle `sync`, but how could I keep a particular one ***"active"*** or ***selected*** in `Android Studio`?

Problem is that after checking out a branch I find the **selected** Build Variant has been reset.

I can not find an "active Build Variant" setting in any project (`idea`) files.

Have already seen this possibly [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431354/how-to-get-the-build-variant-at-runtime-in-android-studio).

Thanks.

**Documentation from `developer.android.com`**:

> After the [Gradle] sync completes, Gradle automatically creates build variants based on your build types and product flavors, and names them according to . For example, if you created "demo" and "full" product flavors, and kept the default "debug" and "release" build types, Gradle creates the following build variants:
>
> `demoDebug`, `demoRelease`, `fullDebug`, `fullRelease`
>
> You can change the build variant to whichever one you want to build and run—just go to
>
> `Build` > `Select Build Variant` and select one from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 10):

**Updates:**

Probably **Android Studio 3.3+** is the way to go, as a new feature **Syncing only active variant** was introduced.

**File** → **Settings** → **Experimental** → **Gradle** → **Only sync the active variant**

---

Here it is. The one circulated by red rectangle is the **active build variant**.

[image]

---

For how to disable the enforced gradle sync:

Go to "**Settings**" -> "**Appearance & Behavior**" -> "**System Settings**"

Uncheck "**Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation**"

But remember to click on the "**Sync Project with Gradle Files**" button whenever you make changes to Gradle.

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to _keep it active_.  For example after checking out the branch, how can the selection be retained.

Comment: When check out the branch, Android Studio will detect the code changes and require a new sync which then deactivate/invalidate  all your build variants. All the build variants before checking out may become invalid after. This is because build variants are dynamically formed according to build types and flavors and hence need an update every time changes detected on gradle files. In other words, this is a behavior supposed to be

Comment: so you're saying it's simply **not possible** (?)

Comment: Every time you have changes to your build.gradle, you for sure need to re sync your project to make AS correctly recognize your current valid build variants, e.g. debugFull, ->debugPro

Comment: just curious about the added value of "keep it active", or you just want to avoid the enforced re-sycn action of Android Studio when you switch between branches?

Comment: In this case, to have a colleague checkout the code and have a particular `build variant` already active.  (So as not to have to specifically select it.)   To propound: if the colleague were to `checkout` and was not aware that multiple `build variants` existed, and was further unaware that one of the `variants` had a _"problem"_ being that the build sought a dependency residing on a VPN and that connection had not been established, consequently causing the IDE to appear to 'hang' to the aforementioned colleague.

Comment: IDE hanging is because of its automatic build according to whatever currently selected build variant. But, this looks still a missing feature for AS...

Comment: Options at **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Compiler** -> **Make project automatically** looks not working ... You can give it a try to uncheck it.

Comment: Thanks for the updates @shizhen, the 'experimental' `Only sync the active variant` is a useful feature.  I do keep `Make project automatically` `off` normally.

Answer (score 3):

This can now be set in the build type with isDefault parameter.

```
android {
   buildTypes {
       debug { isDefault = true }
   }
}
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36988145#comment59

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't really solve the original problem, because a build variant is a combination of flavor AND build type

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that AS (as of Jul 2019) will default to the first **debug** variant on the list, **alphabetically**. If you want it to default to a specific debug variant, see if changing the name to appear first alphabetically works for you.

That said, as a regular non-dev user of Xcode and AS to get access to the builds I need, I'd say that in your specific case OP, it's probably still worth it to teach your colleague what a build variant is, how to select it, and which one is valid for your project for the cases they need to use it in if they're going to be using AS to get builds a lot. Don't just change it to avoid having to explain it to them. That's not helpful to anyone: you're making a bunch of extra work for yourself and they'll never learn anything useful from it that way.

If this is for a stakeholder, rather than having them waste their time fiddling with AS, consider looking into build distribution tools like Fabric. Devs can control what Fabric beta group gets what build(s) and variants for each app pretty well.

I hope this answer helps someone out there. And good luck, OP. :)