# How to get current build variant in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, build, variant

I have a couple of build variants in my Android project.

How to check what variant is compiling in Kotlin code? I want to make a condition like this: If it's **local variant** then do this else if it's **remote variant** do that...

For example something like this :

```
// kotlin code:
if (build.variant=="local") {
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> At build time, Gradle generates the BuildConfig class so your app code
>   can inspect information about the current build.

look at the options provided from that class: [taken from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432225/2299040)

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLCATION_ID = "com.example.app";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "";
}
```

You can also define custom variables according to your requirement:

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // These values are defined only for the release build, which
      // is typically used for full builds and continuous builds.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${minutesSinceEpoch}\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "${minutesSinceEpoch}")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      // Use static values for incremental builds to ensure that
      // resource files and BuildConfig aren't rebuilt with each run.
      // If they were dynamic, they would prevent certain benefits of
      // Instant Run as well as Gradle UP-TO-DATE checks.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "0")
    }
  }
}
```

And to use it:

```
Log.i(TAG, BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME)
Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.build_time))
```

For more [info](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#kotlin)