# How to check Active Build Variant using Terminal or Command prompt?

Tags: android, build.gradle, command-prompt, android-build-flavors

In my project I have three flavors of build `appDebug`, `appRelease`, and `appStaging`.

Now, I want to know which build `variant/flavor` is selected using `terminal/command prompt`.

I want to know currently `selected build variant` using an `android studio terminal or command prompt`.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45595225/6997819

Comment: @VirRajpurohit Exactly. We can easily goto the build config file generated by android studio to get the variant/flavor

Comment: try, this my solution.